# Xcode 4.5 Black Screen or Exception: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have an existing iPhone app that was working fine in Xcode 4.0 prior to upgrading to Xcode 4.5.  Upon upgrading, now I get a Black Screen when running in the iPhone/iPad 4.3 Simulator and get the following Exception when running the iPhone/iPad 6.0 Simulator.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <CCGLView: 0x8c7f380; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <CAEAGLLayer: 0x8c7f670>> is associated with <CCDirectorDisplayLink = 0x994c7f0 | Size: 320 x 480, view = <CCGLView: 0x8c7f380; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <CAEAGLLayer: 0x8c7f670>>>. Clear this association before associating this view with <RootViewController: 0x8c7ef00>.'
```

The app is using Cocos2D 2.0, and is pretty simple based on a tutorial found online.  There is no XIB file.  Everything is being done programmatically.

These are the lines that cause the exception in the 6.0 Simulator (from IOS6TestAppDelegate.m):

```
viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[enter link description here][1]viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

If these lines are commented out, then the 6.0 Simulator shows a black screen as well, instead of the regular menu screen.

I've searched online for solutions on this and tried a number of things, but have been unable to make progress.  I'm fairly new to iPhone programming (though am not new to programming in general) and am really struggling with this.  I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, delete

```
viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

Then replace

```
[window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

With

```
if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

// Create a Navigation Controller with the Director
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director];
navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
NSString *reqSysVer = @"6.0";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
{
    [window setRootViewController:navController];
} else
{
    [window addSubview: navController.view];
}
```

That should do it!

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you so much.  I am now able to move on after about a week of being stuck.